Request for Assistance with Autodesk API Authentication Issue
A screenshot of a computer
Description automatically generated
The account that is connected to the client_id and client_secret that I use has access to all APIs.
A screenshot of a application
Description automatically generated
Since he is already the owner, he has all the permissions.
When I use the access token I receive in some endpoints, it does not give an error, but when I use the APIs in the
https://acc.autodesk.com/docs
Data Management API, it gives this error:
"Token does not have the privilege for this request."
Could you please assist us in resolving this issue? Any guidance on the steps we should take or additional permissions we might need to include would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance.
Dear Autodesk Support Team,
I am writing to request your assistance regarding an issue we are experiencing with Autodesk API authentication. Below are the details of the problem and the steps we have taken:
Authentication API Endpoint:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token
Request Details (Body):
grant_type: client_credentials
client_id: ARmv5G44vD92a6aLeHaTGALb0sBhU0G8
client_secret: bBrLDAYuVAjrHfoK
scope: data:read
Curl Command:
curl -X POST 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=ARmv5G44vD92a6aLeHaTGALb0sBhU0G8&client_secret=bBrLDAYuVAjrHfoK&scope=data:read'
Sample Response:
{
"access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjY0RE9XMnJoOE9tbjNpdk1NU0xlNGQ2VHEwUV9SUzI1NiIsInBpLmF0bSI6ImFzc2MifQ.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJkYXRhOnJlYWQiXSwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiQVJtdjVHNDR2RDkyYTZhTGVIYVRHQUxiMHNCaFUwRzgiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2RldmVsb3Blci5hcGkuYXV0b2Rlc2suY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRvZGVzay5jb20iLCJqdGkiOiJoUGVwQlRVUWEyM2xsY040aTluRm9PbUl1cU44dUgzdzhOeHZudU1hak04OFJDS29WS2d2RHlmaUtUNnV3cnZPIiwiZXhwIjoxNzIyOTg0MjkzfQ.eWQbnaT5kNWq-vplzrCuNV1THECtZ16-LtPpnTJf2nkRAXuFoXOVO96LSYjrdnxiHMi7WZ5qLTQQ3NOAu5nrtQbzen5tzWs7t7Awmntglff5il1wUEfpYNPq8hUXbBkbAjdJ9BLBIPuOvkwynOztAYs_HwnylnSYJbklaIphCz5bB7-aNeO4eBmZACSQHY7wkJ2z6PUB3RlKaAQ4JoJkSPgcX3vReaeFpabyLEaFYigqWAi-etSa8D8_S4lUQ1z1Lh4FjqWw3ZyEzOJuNKhLDHpeNuTaBinQ3N6o_0EM65gNJQ3llcZVzwf_3QOjF5XvLjgovf7ZszhmECcl5dKfMw",

"token_type": "Bearer",

"expires_in": 3599

}
We then use the received access_token to make a POST request to the endpoint https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/sheets/v1/projects/:projectId/storage. However, we are receiving the following response:
Endpoint:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/sheets/v1/projects/:projectId/storage
A screenshot of a computer
Description automatically generated
It appears we are encountering a privilege error with the authorization token, despite ensuring that all necessary permissions are granted.
A screenshot of a computer
Description automatically generated
The account that is connected to the client_id and client_secret that I use has access to all APIs.
A screenshot of a application
Description automatically generated
Since he is already the owner, he has all the permissions.
When I use the access token I receive in some endpoints, it does not give an error, but when I use the APIs in the
https://acc.autodesk.com/docs
Data Management API, it gives this error:
"Token does not have the privilege for this request."
Could you please assist us in resolving this issue? Any guidance on the steps we should take or additional permissions we might need to include would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance.
